# Finding the right drivers in the linux kernel

Tags: kernel-modules, hardware, touchpad

I have an ELAN touch-pad with vendor id 04F3:3128 and I'm trying to find the right Linux kernel drivers to support it. I will start by noting that the touch-pad works with live CDs, like for example Linux Mint. I can, however, not seem to find the right settings in the kernel to get it to work.

(On a live CD where the mouse pad works) if I go into `/sys/bus/hid/devices`, I can find the device here listed as 0018:04F3:3128.0001. If I then `cd` into the device and then into the subsystem directory and then further into the directory drivers, here I can find `hid-generic` and `hid-multitouch`. I have enabled those using `make nconfig` and compiled the kernel, but it still can't find the mouse pad.

How can I find the proper settings (or modules) in the kernel to support my mouse pad?

Comment: See that you have i2c_hid and i2c_hid_acpi. Related: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1086512-start-0.html

Comment: If you're still on this and can read German (Gauss could!): https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8692426.html